# Prevent or delay automatic updates for Chrome Extensions. onUpdateAvailable not working

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have a Chrome extension which can open its own html pages in tabs (ie. the url will be `chrome-extension://extension-id/myPage.html`). When the extension is updated these tabs all get closed automatically, which I want to prevent.

The only suggestions I've found for dealing with this are to use runtime.onUpdateAvailable and/or runtime.onSuspend. But in my test-case neither of them runs!

I have a private test-case extension in the Chrome Web Store so it's using the normal update process. `runtime.onInstalled` saves the manifest version number in local storage when the extension is installed or updated. The browserAction button opens a new tab and prints the contents of local storage to the background page's console.

The onUpdateAvailable code is a follows, and I have something similar for onSuspend:

```
chrome.runtime.onUpdateAvailable.addListener(function(details) {
  chrome.tabs.query({}, function(tabs) {
    chrome.storage.local.set({
      ouaTabs: tabs,
      ouaTabVer: chrome.runtime.getManifest().version
    });
  });
  chrome.storage.local.set({onUpdateAvailable: chrome.runtime.getManifest().version});
});
```

When I print the contents of local storage all I see is the installation and update details. Nothing from onUpdateAvailable or onSuspend is shown.

Looking at the documentation for onUpdateAvailable, perhaps I shouldn't be surprised:

"Fired when an update is available, but isn't installed immediately because the app is currently running."
https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime#event-onUpdateAvailable

Obviously the update IS installed immediately, and that's the problem! But people say this is the right function to use. So the question is...what does an extension need to do for Chrome to consider it to be "currently running" or is there another way to interrupt an automatic update?

Comment: Have you check if your extension if it is running persistently? Based on the [document](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime#event-onUpdateAvailable) : "the update will be installed the next time the background page gets unloaded", may be it stopped or it just gets unloaded that's why the update is installed. If you want check [requestUpdateCheck](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime#method-requestUpdateCheck) for other ways of installing updates. Hope this helps

Comment: It wasn't persistent but I've now tested whether that makes any difference, and unfortunately it doesn't.  With a non-persistent extension I do have a potential solution though: maintain a list of tabs in local storage, and discard the list in the onSuspend event. Check the list in the onInstalled event, and show a notification if the list exists, because this means tabs were closed as a result of the automatic update process. The notification can re-open the tabs when it's clicked.